# non-negative matrix satisfying two conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, economics

A real matrix $B$ is called non-negative if every entry is non-negative. We will denote this by $B\ge 0$.

I want to find a non-negative matrix $B$ satisfying the following two conditions:

(1) $(I-B)^{-1}$ exists but not non-negative. Here $I$ is the identity matrix.

(2) There is a non-zero and non-negative vector $\vec{d}$ such that $(I-B)^{-1}\vec{d}\ge 0$.

I tried all the $2\times 2$ matrices, but it did not work. I conjecture that such a $B$ does not exist, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There are conditions under which $(I-B)^{-1}=I+B+B^2+\ldots$.  In that case it's clear that $(I-B)^{-1}$ would be non-negative.  Any counterexample would have be such that $(I-B)^{-1} \neq I+B+B^{2}+\ldots$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I agree. $B^n$ can not converge to $0$

Comment: So what happens if $B$ is a really big nonnegative matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example $B=diag(1/2,2)$; then $(I-B)^{-1}=diag(2,-1)$ and we can choose $d=[1,0]^T$.

Do you understand why such a $B$ works ?

Comment: The inverse should be diag(2,-1). But I got your point. Your example works! From the economics point of view (input-output model), one industry is profitable, and the other is not. They don't interact with each other.

Comment: Yes, exactly. On the other hand, I go to correct  the miscalculation.